# there is no "Publish Android App" option

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

In the visual studio, there is no the option "Tools | Options | Publish Android App."

I mean there is not (even the deactivated one).

Can you please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean android studio? To my knowledge such a feature was in the pipeline but had not been released. Build your APK, and then upload via the playstore website. If the feature has now been released, make sure you update to the latest android studio

Comment: Publish your apk manually

Comment: No I meant in visual studio, I put it on release mode.

Comment: yes, I published it manually, but I was wondering why it was disappeared. Because some days ago I used it to publish the app.

Comment: Yes, I am also seeing this problem since updating Xamarin to v4.2.0.584. I posted a question in the Xamarin support forums but apparently nobody knows the answer. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/217983#Comment_217983

Comment: @Shaishav: Can you please explain how to publish it manually?